# Saving last window properties/content in javafx

Tags: java, javafx-8

I want to save information from last window (there is possible to use a couple of window in my program) before closing java fx app. 
I tried to do this in `stop()` method, but it saves first opened window.

using `Platform.exit()` stops whole app after closing randow window.
I tried to do some special main window and let user save chosen window by using extra button, but it's not the prettiest solution.

How can I save last used window? Is there any event handler which is gonna solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, a few ways you could try...

1) Inside of your Application class, in the Application#launch method, specify the onCloseRequest event

```
yourStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
    //Do Your on close events here
});
```

2) Inside of your Application class, override the Application#stop method

```
@Override
public void stop(){
    //Do Your on close events here
}
```

And alternatively, you can specify a system shutdown hook for when the jvm exits, which you can do like so

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(() -> whatToDoOnExit());
```